# I can't redirect to another page when I click on listview

Tags: android, kotlin, adapter

I'm designing a phone book application, I've done most things, but I can't go to the profile of the person whose name I clicked. I would appreciate if you explain the use of setOnListener in detail.

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
var listView: ListView? = null

lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView)
    var adapter = UserListAdapter(this, generateData())
    listView?.adapter = adapter

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}

private fun generateData(): ArrayList<UserDto> {
    var result = ArrayList<UserDto>()

    for (i in 0..0) {
        var user = UserDto("Mehmet Gürel", "Dad")
        var user1 = UserDto("Buket Gürel","Mom")
        var user2 = UserDto("Fikret Gürel","First Child")
        var user3 = UserDto("Bilal Gürel","Second Child")
        var user4 = UserDto("Ömer Gürel","Third Child")
        var user5 = UserDto("Ahmet Gürel","Fourth Child")
        var user6 = UserDto("Ronaldo","G.O.A.T")
        var user7 = UserDto("Messi","Pepsi")
        var user8 = UserDto("Kotlin","Thanks to up this")
        var user9 = UserDto("Hatay Dürüm","Bon appetit")
        result.add(user)
        result.add(user1)
        result.add(user2)
        result.add(user3)
        result.add(user4)
        result.add(user5)
        result.add(user6)
        result.add(user7)
        result.add(user8)
        result.add(user9)
    }


    return result

}
```

}

My UserListAdapter codes: i don't know what to do now i hope help me anyone

```
class UserListAdapter(private var activity: Activity, private var items: ArrayList<UserDto>): BaseAdapter() {
private class ViewHolder(row: View?) {
    var txtName: TextView? = null
    var txtComment: TextView? = null

    init {
        this.txtName = row?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtName)
        this.txtComment = row?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtComment)
    }
}
override fun getCount(): Int {
    return items.size
}

override fun getItem(i: Int): Any {
    return items[i]
}

override fun getItemId(i: Int): Long {
    return i.toLong()
}

override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
    val view: View?
    val viewHolder: ViewHolder
    if (convertView == null) {
        val inflater = activity?.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_list_row, null)
        viewHolder = ViewHolder(view)
        view?.tag = viewHolder
    } else {
        view = convertView
        viewHolder = view.tag as ViewHolder
    }

    var userDto = items[position]
    viewHolder.txtName?.text = userDto.name
    viewHolder.txtComment?.text = userDto.comment

    return view as View
}
```

}

Comment: Share your UserListAdapter class too

Comment: Okey i edited bro

Comment: You have to implement the onClick listener inside the adapter where you access viewholder.something. Then using callback communicate to MainActivity to do the work there.

Comment: Can you write the necessary codes? I'm still very new to programming

Comment: Np, I can share you a link to follow it thoroughly u can understand.